# What is a shadow table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

While reading through the docs for the [FTS3 and FTS4](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) extensions for full-text search in SQLite, I notice the use of the term "shadow table". Quote:

> For each FTS virtual table in a database, three to five real (non-virtual) tables are created to store the underlying data. These real tables are called "shadow tables". The real tables are named "%_content", "%_segdir", "%_segments", "%_stat", and "%_docsize", where "%" is replaced by the name of the FTS virtual table.

So what exactly is a shadow table in SQLite? How is it created and used? How is it different from a virtual table or a temporary table?

Googling "SQLite shadow table" doesn't return any meaningful result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual tables are not implemented by the SQLite core itself; all accesses to such a tables are redirected to the respective virtual table module.
This means that when the virtual table module needs to actually store some data, it has to create other tables in the same database.

Shadow tables are created and used automatically by the virtual table module when you're creating and using the virtual table.

You are not supposed to look at or access the shadow tables; they are an implementation detail. Just don't be suprised when they show up in your database.